# Load Component after tab click

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to load and initialize component only when the tab is clicked. The simply example below shows how to put component in content tab. It always initialize with the main component. I ask for advise, how can I make component being loaded after clicked tab?

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="History of User">
      <history-component [someInputProp]="someVariable"></history-component>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Session of User">
      <session-component [someInputProp]="someVariable"></session-component>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

use (select)
(select)="onSelect($event)"

example:

```
 <tab heading="Public Holidays" id="tab5" (select)="onSelect($event)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="selectedTab == 'Public Holidays'">            
                <app-public-holiday-setting></app-public-holiday-setting>
            </ng-container>   
 </tab>
```

in component.ts

```
export class MyTabsComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedTab: string;
    constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelect(data: TabDirective)
  {
    this.selectedTab = data.heading;
  }

}
```

Comment: your solution (above) works when there are two tabs only and one will be loaded when page loads and second one will be loaded on click. Yes, this works when there are two tabs only.

What if there are more than 2 tabs say 4 tabs.? I'm sure that hardcoding `*ngIf="selectedTab == 'tab_heading'"` will not be good solution..

Please help.

Comment: i can use on many tabs using this way. you can use tab id as well.

Comment: how?? Could you please explain or please post the snippet here(with more than 2 tabs).

I do not want to do this. `*ngIf="selectedTab == 'Public Holidays'"`.